# Android toolbar shadow

Tags: android, xml

So I created a toolbar and tabview, but I can't remove the shadow below the toolbar as you can see here:
[image: picture]

This is my toolbar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

What am I missing? I tried to remove shadow with all methods I could find on Internet, but none of them helped.
If you need me to upload any more core just say!

Thanks!

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        -->
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>



    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        -->
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>


        />
</style>
</resources>
```

styles v21

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vjezbe);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: add this to toolbar in xml: 
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
and check it

Comment: have you increased value for elevation?

Comment: I don't think so. Would it help if I copy styles.xml?

Answer (score 1):

use `app:elevation="0dp"` instead of **android:elevation**

Comment: Are you using an AppBarLayout? If you are, the elevation should be set on it.

Comment: Sorry, how do I know if I use AppBarLayout?

Comment: This would wrap your ToolBar component in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it programatically...

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

and change ur style to

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#5C2D91</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

and set the actionbar style as

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

in

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: The OP has tried that already, it was in my answer, but have deleted/edited it by now.

Comment: When i paste that code into fragment.java i get errors all the time

Comment: Did it but getting nullpointerexception. Look at my OP, it's updated